# JButton is not enabling when have result set in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Following code is to enable button `greceived_btn`when result set contain data.

But the button is not enabling when the SQL criteria met.

What is the error here?

```
    public void enableBtn() throws SQLException{

    greceived_btn.setEnabled(false);

    if(poNo.getSelectedItem()!=null){

    String no = poNo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String not="no";

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM pointoinvoce WHERE PONo=? AND GoodsRecieved=?";   

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, no);
    pst.setString(2, not);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            greceived_btn.setEnabled(true); 
        }else{
            greceived_btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are potentially a large number of reasons that this might happen. One, for example, is you're shadowing or changing the button variables reference. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You should also be releasing the database resources (`pst`, `rs`) when you're done with them, consider having a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: btw the code can be shortened without the consequences to the logic: 
change `if(rs.next()){ greceived_btn.setEnabled(true); }else{ greceived_btn.setEnabled(false);}` to `greceived_btn.setEnabled(rs.next());`.

The line `greceived_btn.setEnabled(false);` could be removed too. IMHO the method is `enableBtn() /* meant to enable the button */`. It looks somewhat  awkward to have the first action in this method to **disable the button**. Looks like the line `greceived_btn.setEnabled(false);` should not belong to this method.